# laravel: global middleware stack for bypassing ngrok browser warning doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, ngrok

created this middleware and attached it to global middleware stack but doesn't work. still getting the browser warning on browser.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NgrokMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('ngrok-skip-browser-warning', '1231');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

[image]

anyone knows what happens here?

Comment: Why not use some other service like https://pinggy.io or Cloudflare Tunnel ? It seems you are editing request headers. You need to edit response header instead.

Answer (score 0):

The headers need to go in the response rather than the request. In practice, the response is what comes out of the `$next` function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NgrokMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('ngrok-skip-browser-warning', '1231');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I tried this